# Changes to spatial_ref_sys tables do not take affect

Tags: postgis, srid

I made changes to the `spatial_ref_sys` table in my PostGIS database but using `ST_SetSRID` and `ST_Transform` doesn't seem to be affected by the changes.
For instance, I changed the proj4text because it was incorrect for EPSG 2039 and it still used the original one. I set the srtext to null to make sure it doesn't use it.
I then deleted the whole row but it ignores all changes to this table.
I even tried to restart the postgres service.
Any ideas?

Comment: By http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/02/proj4-postgis.html I guess that proj4text is never checked because Proj finds the EPSG:2039 definitions from its own proj.db database.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/02/proj4-postgis.html, the `authname` and `authsrid` take precedence over the other fields.
So the only way to make changes to an EPSG projection is to break the connection between the PostGIS SRID and the EPSG ID. Pretend that that projection is not defined by EPSG but a custom one:

```
UPDATE spatial_ref_sys
SET auth_name = 'roni',
    auth_srid = ...,
    srtext = '...',
    proj4text = '...'
WHERE srid = 2309;
```

Comment: Or insert a new custom projection into spatial_ref_sys with an unused srid (e.g., 990099), then write your query in terms of the new srid. This leaves the existing srid unchanged in the table if there other uses for it.